# How to passing data between 3 activities (Android Studio)

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWCKR.png)

look at image link above, how to code that simple passing data between 3 activities?

Activity 1:

- input name
- then click insert button
- then intent to Activity 2

Activity 2:

- click show button
- then intent to Activity 3

Activity 3:

- setText the input name from Activity 1

Maybe i should have use setter getter? but how?

I need this for learning the basic, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Activity 1:on click listener of insert button put this:

```
   Intent  i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
   String name = input.gettext();
   i.putExtra("name",name);
   StartActivity(i);
```

above code will pass value from activity 1 to activity 2,i assume you are quite new to android development [go through this link carefully to understand Intents and starting activity](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Now in Activity2 get the values from intent

```
  String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

name will have value passed from activity 1;

Now following same pattern you can pass value from activity 2 to activity 3

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways , but here is one,

When ever your moving from Activity A to Activity B (probably on button click) pass the inputName to B activity

ActivityA.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("DATA", "inputName");
startActivity(i);
```

ActivityB.java doesn't do anything about it but it must be seen before ActivityC.

So the info u pass from A to B you need to check and pass it to C while moving from B to C

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
}
startActivity(newIntent);
```

In Activity C you can get the data like this and use

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String data1 = b.getString("DATA");
```

This is one simple solution and there are many other ways you can try like

- Storing in Shared pref and retrieving
- Using application class
- Using some interface etc but in your case this simple solution is enough i guess

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 intent.putExtra("name","value");
```

Comment: i tried that intent, that's not enough explanation... i don't understand how to passing data between 3 activities.. i don't know how to use setter getter.

Comment: i think this is the best way to pass data between activity.